# Integral of $x^2 \cos(a x)\; \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> $\int x^2 \cos(a x)\; \mathrm{d}x$

I thought this would be simple and I am pretty sure this is the answer:

> $I =\frac{x^2\sin(ax)}{a}+\frac{2x\cos(ax)}{a^2}+\frac{2\sin(ax)}{a^3}$

I have been told that this *isn't* the correct answer?

I just applied integration by parts twice. Is my answer essentially correct other than typographical errors(sign change) etc, or have I seriously diverged from the correct calculation?

Comment: It's the right idea, but check the sign on the last term.

Comment: The second $+$ sign should be a minus.

Comment: Here is the answer:$$ {\frac {{x}^{2}\sin \left( ax \right) }{a}}-2\,{\frac {\sin \left( ax
 \right) }{{a}^{3}}}+2\,{\frac {x\cos \left( ax \right) }{{a}^{2}}}
 $$

Comment: You can straightforwardly check your answer via direct differentiation; you'll find that, with the sign as you've got it in your OP, the $2x \cos x$ term won't be cancelled out.

Comment: @Semiclassical I am embarrassed that I didn't do that! I will always do that in future thank you.

Yes you are all right above, I made a mistake on a sign transcription

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by other users: You have made a typographical error. Specifically the second sign below should be a minus, as seen below:

> $I =\frac{x^2\sin(ax)}{a}+\frac{2x\cos(ax)}{a^2}-\frac{2\sin(ax)}{a^3}$

Note, the error would likely have occured when you were applying the minus form the first integration by parts, onto the second one. E.g:

$\int uv =u(\int v\;\mathrm{d}x)-\int u'(\int v \;\mathrm{d}x) \;\mathrm{d}x \Rightarrow$ $$u(\int v \;\mathrm{d}x) - (u'\int v \;\mathrm{d}x -\int u''(\int\int v \;\mathrm{d}x\;\mathrm{d}x)\;\mathrm{d}x)$$
$$u(\int v \;\mathrm{d}x) - u'\int v \;\mathrm{d}x +\int u''(\int\int v \;\mathrm{d}x\;\mathrm{d}x)\;\mathrm{d}x$$

Note the bracket removal in the last step.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int x^2\cos(ax)dx=|u=x^2\Rightarrow du=2xdx, dv=\cos(ax)dx\Rightarrow v=\frac{1}{a}\sin(ax)|=$$
$$=\frac{x^2}{a}\sin(ax)+\frac{2}{a}\int x\sin(ax)dx=\frac{x^2}{a}\sin(ax)+\frac{2}{a}I_1$$
$$I_1=\int x\sin(ax)dx=|u=x\Rightarrow du=dx, dv=\sin(ax)dx\Rightarrow v=\frac{1}{a}\cos(ax)|=$$
$$=\frac{x}{a}\cos(ax)+\frac{1}{a}\int\cos(ax)dx=\frac{x}{a}\cos(ax)-\frac{1}{a}\cdot\frac{1}{a}\sin(ax)dx=\frac{x}{a}\cos(ax)-\frac{1}{a^2}\sin(ax)dx$$

$$\int x^2\cos(ax)dx=\frac{x^2}{a}\sin(ax)+\frac{2}{a}I_1=\frac{x^2}{a}\sin(ax)+\frac{2}{a}\left(\frac{x}{a}\cos(ax)-\frac{1}{a^2}\sin(ax)dx\right)=$$
$$=\frac{x^2}{a}\sin(ax)+\frac{2x}{a^2}\cos(ax)-\frac{2}{a^3}\sin(ax)$$

i.e.

$$\int x^2\cos(ax)dx=\frac{x^2}{a}\sin(ax)+\frac{2x}{a^2}\cos(ax)-\frac{2}{a^3}\sin(ax)$$